# ES6: SintaxError: Unexpected token import NodeJS

Tags: node.js, babeljs, nodemon

I don't understand what is wrong. Node v10.5.0 NPM v6.14.8

The .babelrec:

```
  {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
            {
                "asyncGenerators": true,
                "generators": true,
                "async": true
            }
        ],
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                "corejs": false,
                "helpers": true,
                "regenerator": true,
                "useESModules": false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

The package.json

```
"main": "src/app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nps",
    "test": "npm start test",
    "build": "npm start build",
    "presetup": "npm install",
    "setup": "npm start config && npm start setup.script"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "NodeJS",
    "TypeScript",
    "express"
  ],
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10"
}
```

The tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "pretty": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.core",
            "es2015.collection",
            "es2015.generator",
            "es2015.iterable",
            "es2015.promise",
            "es2015.proxy",
            "es2015.reflect",
            "es2015.symbol",
            "es2015.symbol.wellknown",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ]
    }
```

Command for transpile: ./node_modules/.bin/babel dist -d dist

When execute npm start, return this error: Application is crashed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.
If remove in .babelrec the plugins, return this error: Application is crashed: ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined.
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Type in the file name `.babelrec`. Should be `.babelrc`.

Comment: Also, you do not need Babel if you transpile from TS to JS. Try adding this to `tsconfig.json`: `"target": "ES2017",` and `"lib": ["es2017"],`

Comment: Hi Vasyl! I made both suggestions. Changed name for .babelrc and error persists. In tsconfig.json the target cotains value "es6" and lib contais "es6" and error persists.

Comment: Try removing Babel from your project. Rely only on the `tsc` - TypeScript Compiler.

Comment: I removed and tried, returned the same error. I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days. rs!

Comment: Try transpiling to ES5 using the tsc.

Comment: Here are few more TS options for you to try: `"esModuleInterop": true` and `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: The error persists. In server production contains the pm2, when execute command pm2 start dist/app.js in log generated contais this error syntax error: unexpected token. This error is returned in both ways of transplanting.

Comment: I put my tsconfig.json complete in question.

Comment: Can you execute the app using node 10 on your machine?